# How to display Tinybox 2 popup box on blogger?

Tags: popup, blogger

I'm using this code to display [Tinybox](http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/03/javascript-modal-windows/) popup box

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function()
   {
      TINY.box.show(html:'Hello', 1, 400, 350, 1)
   }
</script>
```

Insteed of plan text 'Hello' I want to show text designed in html and css ,
on website i can show html page using this

```
TINY.box.show('contentfile.html', 1, 400, 350, 1)
```

But how can i do this in blogger because?

Answer (score 0):

You can host .html file on other site like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function()
   {
     TINY.box.show('http://exapmle.com/contentfile.html', 1, 400, 350, 1)
   }
</script>
```

Comment: where i host my file? is i need to buy hosting?